# Mirror programming for uicontrols in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multilingual

I am new to multi-language app.
What I am doing is,
an app with two languages.
English & Arabic

The language of the app depends upon the device language.
(I want to change this too, that app language should be controlled from inside the app. not device dependant but thats next question)

I am having some controls like `UIButton`,`UITextField`,`UILabel`, etc....

When my app is in English I gave these controls frame starting from left corner of device, and when my app is in Arabic I gave them frames starting from Right corner of device. (As arabic is written from Right - to - left)

My Question is,
For this purpose I need to do extra work,
i.e. check device language and then set the frames of control.
on each view I may have "n" number of controls, and giving the frame sizes to all controls for both language doesn't seems good from my view.

Is there anything available in `Xcode` itself by using which I can do this.
means I need to give frames for default language (i.e. English) and if my device language is change to Arabic then frames of Controls will be automatically Mirrored from Right to left.

Following screens may give some idea.
(I used different frames for all those controls checking device language)

Any help is accepted.

Thanks in advance.
sorry If question is asked already. But I didn't find anything.
If anyone found then link to that is Welcome :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Supporting Right-to-Left Languages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html):

> Your user interface should be mirrored when displaying right-to-left languages. If you use base internationalization and Auto Layout, most of the user interface will appear mirrored automatically for you. The text direction changes to right-to-left with the exception of phone numbers and country codes which are always left-to-right. Some views and controls in your user interface may not change direction automatically which you can fix programmatically.

---

They functionality you're looking for is called Auto Layout which was introduced a few years ago by Apple. It will handle lots of things you need, but there's also a lot to do for you. The guide above will guide you through the necessary steps.

---

**Update** from [iOS 9.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-DontLinkElementID_11):

> iOS 9 brings comprehensive support for right-to-left languages, which makes it easier for you to provide a flipped user interface. For example:
>
> - Standard UIKit controls automatically flip in a right-to-left context.
> - `UIView` defines semantic content attributes that let you specify how particular views should appear in a right-to-left context.
> - `UIImage` adds the `imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection` method, which makes it easy to flip an image programmatically when appropriate.
>   To learn more about providing a flipped user interface, see Supporting Right-to-Left Languages.

Comment: :- Thanks for this document. But can you please little bit elaborate. as I have to use this feature in both ways that is programatically and using storyboard as well

Comment: It seems like lots of UI elements will automatically mirror expect for those noted in this document.

Comment: can i change L To R and R To L of views by button in my application?

Comment: @SyedFarazHaiderZaidi It will switch automatically to RTL if you set up Auto Layout properly. It's all documented in my answer, please read it completely!

Comment: @FabioPoloni your answer supposed to work in a case where we change iphone language from setting. i'm unchecking "Respect to language" for some controls but not everything, but how will i force my viewcontroller to "Respect for language" when i click arabic button inside my application.

Comment: @SyedFarazHaiderZaidi Where did you set that? I assume it's not easily done as you might want it to be.